# Image from URL attached to image_tag won't display in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I'm pulling back data from an object with intentions to display an image in a view. I'm debugging the object to my browser and this is what I see:

```
image: !ruby/object:Parse::File
parse_filename: xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-image.jpg
url: http://files.parse.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-image.jpg
```

**In my view I've tried the following:**

```
<%= image_tag object["url"] %>
<%= image_tag object["parse_filename"] %>
```

However the image is never shown.

Googled but can't find much information on how to this any other way. As far as I know this should but it doesn't.

Would appreciate some help

Thanks for your time

**Update full debug result:**

```
--- !ruby/hash:Parse::Object
alternativeColour: false
collection: 1
colour: 2
favourite: false
gender: 2
image: !ruby/object:Parse::File
 parse_filename: sds232-eee7-4203-840b-jk233k23232-image3.jpg
 url: http://files.parse.com/sdsd232-7f16-sd23-sds2-a4c7884d118e/dcefd915-eee7-4203-840b-jk233k23232-image3.jpg
price: 23.42
productType: 2
recommended: false
size: 6
title: Bomber Jacket
createdAt: '2014-04-03T20:33:41.020Z'
updatedAt: '2014-06-18T19:03:24.220Z'
objectId: yZksdhNJPm
```

Comment: Are you sure the key `parse_filename` is a string and not a symbol?

Comment: @Vimsha how do I check? It just looks like a file path to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to access using object["image"].url. I was wondering why url and file_pathname was slightly indented under image. Now I realise why.

```
image["image"].url
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're not using the proper object or attribute.

First, try to print the image using the URL like this:

```
<%= image_tag "http://files.parse.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-image.jpg" %>
```

Once that's working, try getting the correct object and attribute. Next line should give you all object details

```
<%= debug object %>
```

If it prints nothing, check your controller variables and how you're using them on the view

UPDATE:

According to the full object debug message, the property should be accessed as `object["image"].url`
Cheers

Comment: Raw url works if I copy and paste the url that the object returns. I'm currently already using debug object and it is returning what I expect. Just a bit confused as to why the value of the object["url"] doesn't work.

Comment: Can you paste here the output of <%= debug object %>?

Comment: Or better: try object.url and let me know the result!

Comment: Output of debug object is pasted in the question. The only thing it's missing is --- !ruby/hash:Parse::Object at the start and other properties such as "title", "price" which are all displaying correct values. I'm accessing them using object["title"], object["price"]

Comment: Seeing the full debug message will help me understand what object are you dealing with. You might anonymize any sensible attribute if you want, but it's really helpful to have the whole message to see nested properties

Comment: Added the full debug.

Comment: Hmm I just done "debug["image"] and it returned the url and path_filename. So I guess I have to try access the URL via image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58812/discussion-between-fjuan-and-londonguy).